# How to Resize image and reduce DPI using Imagemagick in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am trying to resize image and reduce its DPI both at once using package.

I am using im.convert() instead of im.resize() because I have other options as well that needs to be specified. I tried to pass an array with all the options to the im.convert(), but I am getting an error that says "Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -units"

```c
const inputPath = "E:\PC\lister\uploads\dbmid_AAAeU6UkAOHoUmq6t25RPjK6g1sfK6gn7fg\Clients\Matt\2019-06-10T03-32-02.385Z45.jpg";'

const outputPath= "E:\PC\lister\uploads\dbmid_AAAeU6UkAOHoUmq6t25RPjK6g1sfK6gn7fg\Clients\Matt\Web\2019-06-10T03-32-02.385Z45.jpg";
const args = [
    inputPath,
    "-units",
    "pixelsperinch",
    "-density",
    "75x75",
    "-resize",
    "1920",
    outputPath
]
im.convert(args, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if(err) console.log(err)

});
```

I am expecting the resized image with 75dpi in the folder called 'web' that I specified in the `outputPath` above. but I am getting an error that says "Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -units"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistakenly running a Microsoft-supplied program called `CONVERT.EXE` that converts FAT filesystems to NTFS (or something similar) rather than the **ImageMagick** command you want. Depending on the version of **ImageMagick** you want to use, the solution is potentially different.

---

If you want to use **ImageMagick** v7 (which is the best and a sensible idea), the commands have changed as follows:

```
Old v6 command |  New v7 command
===============|================
identify       | magick identify
animate        | magick animate
montage        | magick montage
convert        | magick
mogrify        | magick mogrify
```

So, you need to change your Javascript to use `magick` rather than `convert`.

---

If you want to use v6 **ImageMagick**, you need to continue to use `convert` but ensure that Windows finds **ImageMagick** `convert` rather than Windows `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONVERT.EXE`. You can either do that by explicitly running the full **ImageMagick** command, so instead of plain `convert` you use the full path which will look roughly like this:

```
C:\ImageMagick\ImageMagick-6.7.6\convert ...
```

or you set your `PATH` in some GUI window ( I avoid Windows, but it's something like `Settings`->`Control Panel`->`System`->`Environment Variables`->`PATH`) and make it so the directory containing ImageMagick is at the front so Windows finds ImageMagick before its own `CONVERT.EXE`:

```
PATH=C:\ImageMagick\ImageMagick-6.7.6:<REST OF PATH>
```

Comment: Or just rename ImageMagick convert to IM_convert.